# How do I write this one specific mod_rewrite directive?

Tags: .htaccess

Hi I am new to mod_rewrite and I need to rewrite the following uri:
**testsite/payBill?token=EC-8TM276595T982014G&PayerID=V3GMCKGHW5XXU** 
to something like this 
**testsite/index.php?PayBill&token=$1&PayerID=$2**

I have been searching all over including some examples from this site but not succeeded in finding something similar to my case.

**...Revision** 
To be more specific:
 This is my base: **RewriteBase /tshirtshop** .

 and this is the URL I need to rewrite.

**https://localhost/tshirtshop/payBill?token=EC-2FT032799N454992F&PayerID=V3GMCKGHW5XXU**

to something like:

**https://localhost/tshirtshop/index.php?PayBill&token=$1&PayerID=$2**

Comment: is the `PayBill` in `testsite/index.php?PayBill&token=$1&PayerID=$2` required or is it a typo?

Comment: PayBill is required and very necessary.

Comment: None of the suggestions so far has worked.

Comment: I edited to include https and tshirtshop. If it does not work can you provide more details e.g. test url you are using and the result you get and how it is different than your expected result.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tshirtshop/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tshirtshop/paybill  [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^token=(.+)&payerid=(.+)  [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php?PayBill&token=%1&PayerID=%2 [L]
```

Comment: .htaccess is in the tshirtshop directory.

Comment: ok - edited to reflect that .htaccess is in tshirtshop dir

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
RewriteEngine On

# Either RewriteBase has to point to the base or the RewriteRule has to be ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] not ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteBase /testsite/

# Only do this when the file doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Only do this when the directory  doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?(.*)$ /index.php?$1&$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Mod rewrite is used to transform one URL into another or reflect contents of one into another one. If the data of the result URL is not contained in the original one then I don’t think that it is possible to do.

Maybe you want to achieve this with PHP, I suggest you to rewrite all URLs into a main PHP file and then control all the navigation flow from there.